# Help on creating a php function

Tags: php, function

I always find working through a specific example helps me understand - so I'd like to see how to convert code into a function I can call over and over.

This code reads a date from a custom field in wordpress called 'date' in the format YYYYMMDD and shows it as a full length friendly date (eg 'Monday 1st January 2001'). I's like to move it as a function in `function.php` file so I can call it from different places, and understand how that conversion happened.

```
<?php
$date = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'date', true);
if ($date){
$mydate = "$date";
echo date('l, j F, Y', strtotime($mydate));
}
?>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Why the `$mydate = "$date";`? Use casting `$mydate = (string) $date;`. You can even do it right in the function `echo date('l, j F, Y', strtotime((string) $date));`

Comment: Have your checked **[the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.returning-values.php)**?

Comment: @netcoder I have looked at some tutorials, problem is I don't understand a lot of the way the explanations are phrase - I don't know what the original code dopes, so I find it hard to pick apart!!! Thanks for the link thoough, I'll give it a try.

Comment: @TomcatExodus I mostly just mine code from elsewhere, I'm kind of learning what it all means - but I don't really understand what you suggested - I'll trial and error a bit to see if I can get it to work!

Comment: @Jorge have you ever done **any** coding? the way functions are in php is basically the same  as in most programming languages.

Comment: no not really! I'm breaking through from html into php now reall!

Comment: @JorgeLuisBorges What I was referring to is *type casting*, the process of changing a values type, say from `int` to `string` as in your question. The quotes surrounding `$date` implicitly cast the value to the string type. Casting explicitly, via `(string)` or `(int)` is, I believe, the best way to achieve this. Just a caveat; make the PHP manual your best friend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function get_wp_date($post){
    $date = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'date', true);
    if ($date){
       $mydate = "$date";
       return date('l, j F, Y', strtotime($mydate));
    }
    return false;
}
```

Then call it by doing:

```
echo get_wp_date($post);
```

You might want to validate it 1st so you make sure it does not return `false`

Comment: And how he supposed to access `$post->ID` ?

Comment: @LazyOne -- I am under the assumption that `$post` is some wp global var. the OP did not show where or how it was defined

Comment: @Neal If it was global, you still have to address it properly, right? No-one has cancelled the variable visibility yet. Just... the original answer was not a great example that can be given to a not-that-experienced person (like OP apparently is). Now is good and I can sleep well :) .

Comment: @Neal thanks - that seems to work, unfortunately I don't really understand it. I get most of it, I just don't know what the ($post) bit means - in general, what does the bit in brackets after the function mean? Basically I keep asking people how to do stuff, I'm trying to figure out how to do it myself in future...

Comment: @JorgeLuis -- what bit in brackets?? i just copied your code and pasted it into a function....

Comment: @Neal `function get_wp_date($post){`   the ($post) in brackets in that bit there -wasn't in my original code.

Comment: @Neal do you see the bit in the code that says ($post) - I don't know why you put that in there. I'm just trying to understand

Comment: @JorgeLuisBorges You see `$post` being used in your code, right. because your code was declared in global scope so the `$post` variable. Because global variables are "invisible" inside function, it needs to be passed there somehow. One of the ways (preferred/highly recommended in this case) is to pass as function parameter. Really, read the docs

Comment: @LazyOne Thanks for the help - I guess my real question was trying to get my head round defining function parameters. FYI, have read the docs - they are quite hard to take in. Trying to teach myself, Most docs assume some level of understanding. Its hard to go through them all without having anyone to ask what might seem like stupid questions. Seems like this site isn't the place to ask those kind of questions - which seems odd as people seem quite happy to solve simple problems, but not so keen to explain them. I guess I'll go back to asking questions each and every time I need an answer.

Comment: I appreciate the help - I really, really do - but honestly, if you didn't already know php, would you understand what "By default, function arguments are passed by value (so that if the value of the argument within the function is changed, it does not get changed outside of the function). To allow a function to modify its arguments, they must be passed by reference. " meant (that's an explanation taken from the site you referrred me to!) Its all quite a tough nut to crack. Thanks again though.

Comment: @JorgeLuisBorges - feel free to jump into [chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11/php) :)

Comment: @JorgeLuisBorges - That description you quoted does not have anything PHP-specific in it... So yes, if I didn't already know PHP, I would understand what it means, because of the other coding I had done.  *Have* you ever programmed before?

Comment: @JMTyler lol -- that goes back up to my comment on the Question :-)

Comment: @salathe - lol just jumped into the chat - unsurprisingly I don't have enough rep to join in, would love to though!

Comment: @JMTyler - nope, not really - I've been messing around with code fairly trial and error for a while, but don't really know what it all means. Never had any help, just didn't want to be one of those people who just gets answers without understanding - guess I'll just go back to muddling through, as asking doesn't help.

Comment: @salathe, by the way - looking at the chat - I'm pretty good with the loop, and I can write custom queries - I've just never had to write a function, I don't really understand the decision making process involved in choosing a variable for a function, and then how to use it. I the that $post queries the post table in the database, I just don't really get how function variables are pushed into the containing php, and how to differentiate between user defined and floating variables

Comment: @JorgeLuisBorges If you want to learn some programming consider taking some courses or buy yourself simple PHP book (even "Teach yourself PHP in 24-hours" will do for now) -- PHP manual is not a good place to learn programming language -- dedicated book will be MUCH more useful. PHP manual will be your next step after the book (or together with the book if you need some technical clarification).

Comment: @TheLazyOne - thanks - that's the best and most helpful answer I've had so far!

Comment: @LazyOne see above @Jorge -- remember to type usernames at least close to correct for the 1st 3 or four characters or else the user does not get notified